# SyntaxError: %time pickle.dump

Tags: python, time, syntax, syntax-error, pickle

Can someone please explain to me how the %time works?
I got this from a book but every time I use it, I get an error. 
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
path = '/home/foad/PythonBoken/flash/'

import numpy as np
from random import gauss

a = [gauss(1.5, 2) for i in range(100000)] #generation of normally distributed randoms

#Write this list above to disk for later retrieval
import pickle 

pkl_file=open(path + 'data.pkl', 'w') #open file for writing. Existing file may be overwritten

%time pickle.dump(a, pkl_file)
```

Comment: It's an IPython magic command and is meant to be used at the IPython prompt / command line: https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/dev/interactive/magics.html#magic-time

Comment: I am using the Spyder IDE with IPython console but still get an error message stating that "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" at the %.